# How do you pass access to a shared Array to a Python Process that is already running when using the Multiprocessing package?

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I need to pass hexadecimal data from one multiprocessing processes to another in real time. I plan to use a multiprocessing.Array type to do this. However, the start time of the processes will be dependant on external events and so the process that sends the data and will also create the array, may start after the receiving process starts. This means I cannot pass the Array as an argument to the receiving process when it is initiated.

I had come up with the idea of maintaining a list of array objects (long term there will be several sending processes) using the multiprocessing.manager.list() type. However, on testing with the following code (which has been simplified as much as possible), I have received the error message below.

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Array,Lock,Manager
import time 
def producer(buffers):
   #create multiprocessing.array
   byte_arr=Array('i',1)
   byte_arr[0]=20
   #add array to the list
   buffers.append(['test1',byte_arr])

if __name__ == '__main__':

   lock=Lock()
   manager=Manager()
   
   #shared list of array names and objects
   source_buffers=manager.list()

   # start the processes
   producer_process = Process(target=producer,args=(source_buffers,))
   producer_process.start()
   
   while True:
       print(source_buffers)
       time.sleep(0.5)
```

Error message:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/test.py", line 9, in producer
    buffers.append(['test1',byte_arr])
  File "<string>", line 2, in append
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 817, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 199, in __reduce__
    assert_spawning(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 359, in assert_spawning
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: SynchronizedArray objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

The last line seems to say that what I want to do is impossible.
If anyone has any ways around it or other ideas of how the problem can be solved, any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: why not just use a pipe or queue?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: For both you need to pass the arguments to the processes when they start. I want to have multiple readers able to view the data coming from the producer process and pipe only allows a one to one connection and using a queue each message only gets sent to one of the listeners meaning they don't get all get all of the data. I'm thinking of using the multiprocessing.connection package now though.

Comment: why not have the parent process forward everything on as required between your workers?  alternatively, if you have a large amount of data to move you can `mmap` some shared region and just send offsets between processes

Comment: I've come up with a solution: I'm going to use multiprocessing.connection to create connections between the processes and then all you need to pass to the child processes is the port number.